# What's the sense of [sql-and] and [sql-or] when we have [logical-and] and [logical-or]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

While browsing the newly created tags, I bumped into [sql-and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-and) and [sql-or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-or). There are just a few questions about those tags (two and three) and I don't see the need of having those tags, as we already have [logical-and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical-and) and [logical-or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical-or), hence this question for a synonym-request.

Comment: I'd say just nuke those, they aren't really useful

Comment: Agreed. A question can have `sql` and `logical-and`, so it doesn't need an extra one.

Comment: The tagged questions have already been retagged or deleted, so there is no need for a full burnination process, is there?

Comment: Actually, yes, given there are ~5 questions total, no full-scale burnination is necessary here.

Comment: SQL does not use [Boolean logic](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) but [three-valued logic](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#SQL) (corresponding to "Yes", "No", and "Unknown") and thus its logical operators behave differently than logical operators in practically all other mainstream programming languages. The description of the tags [tag:logical-and] and [tag:logical-or] *specifically* excludes anything other than bivalent logic, so they cannot be used for SQL, at least not with the current descriptions. The current tags descriptions are not just wrong for SQL, but …

Comment: … actively misleading in *exactly* those aspects that SQL's three-valued logic differs from the more common two-valued logic.

Comment: I'd like to know why there are separate [tag:and] and [tag:or] tags at all? [tag:boolean-logic] and [tag:sql-logic] are much more appropriate.  Or even just a [tag:logic] tag paired with [tag:sql] or [tag:boolean].

Comment: @Spencer:  No one™ thinks in terms of "SQL logic"; they see "and" in SQL and they ask a question about "and" in SQL.  There's very little value that I can see in adding more terminology just to confuse folks if they're used to asking about SQL's and and SQL's or.

Comment: @Makoto As I see it, [tag:sql-and] is what's adding the unnecessary terminology and tags.

Comment: @Spencer:  If they're synomized to sql, then there wouldn't be extra terminology since the synonym would reduce back to one generic tag.

Comment: @Makoto In the case of and and or, that's probably the best solution because of the special status of and and or (which I just learned about today).

Comment: Would be nice if we had some more intelligent system for automatic retagging.

Comment: @Makoto While I don't agree with Spencer's prescription for replacement tags, I second the base question: why do the logical operators need a *dedicated tag*? How do these tags help reach experts for better answers? (Tags don't help with finding questions for your own research, especially when they are as fine grained as specific mathematical operators. Good titles help more.) A tag for Boolean logic is more useful.

Comment: re "dedicated tag" for operators: so you ask your question one way, say for `and`, then someone suggests you apply De Morgan's laws and now you have to retag it for `or`?

Comment: @jpmc26 "*Tags don't help with finding questions for your own research*" - uh, but they do?

Comment: @Bergi Nope. Stack Overflow's search is crappy, so you're better off using an actual search engine which doesn't even recognize the tags. (That's where the vast majority of incoming traffic for people looking for an existing question is going to come from, anyway.) Additionally, most people aren't going to search on such an obscure, ridiculously specific tag in the first place. Most people aren't going to realize those tags exist. So those tags are not helping people with questions find existing questions.

Comment: @jpmc26 People with questions are not the only people looking for questions. Tags help a lot with finding duplicates and related questions. If you don't want to use tags that's fine, but then please don't remove tags that other do want to use.

Comment: @Bergi Duplicates rarely have the same tags, unless those tags are broad tags like the languages or platforms the question involves. You're better off with good search terms in a search engine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can only assume this is an outflow of other necessary tags like [sql-order-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-order-by). Sometimes people want to tag all the things, and use other subtags to justify that.

I tend to agree with Jörg W Mittag that SQL logic is very different from programming logic here. I am inclined to think these should be synonyms of [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), which [already has several synonyms like this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/synonyms)

Comment: Agreed, but see my comment to OP.

Comment: This makes the best sense; if someone is asking about and `AND`/`OR` in SQL, then they are asking about SQL, so the important tags are going to be [[tag:sql]] and (probably) their RDBMS; having a tag for the and/or isn't going to add any benefit;  I've suggested the synonyms, as no one else has as yet, for what it's worth.

Comment: [tag:sql-order-by] strikes me as unnecessary and unhelpful.

Comment: @jpmc26 What's unhelpful about that tag? It seems to very useful to me.

Comment: @Bergi Tags are not for specifying the details of a question. That's what the title is for. Tags are for reaching experts in a subject, putting the question in their feed. As such, they're only good when they address broad subjects that an expert would follow if they want to answer questions in that category. The `ORDER BY` operator is not such a subject. "SQL" is. Just go look at how poorly it's used in practice by browsing through the questions.

Comment: @jpmc26 Tags obviously cannot ask a question, there's no question mark in them, nobody is using them to specify the details of a question. Sure titles should be used for that, but look at how crappy titles are in practice - should we get rid of them and just read the whole question text every time? No, obviously not, and tags serve a similar purpose - they tell experts from a broad area what particular topic the question is about. The ordering of rows in a result set certainly is such a subject, as is the ternary logic.

Comment: @Bergi People who make crappy titles will also have crappy tags. You can't help people who won't help themselves. "they tell experts from a broad area what particular topic the question is about" Not if they never reach the expert because the broader tag wasn't included, and if the broader tag is required, then a narrower tag doesn't help. The expert is going to learn much more about the specific question from the title than they ever will the tag. As an answerer, seeing a question tagged as involving "order by" in no way helps me understand what it is asking or whether I can answer it.

Comment: It's been almost a week I've launched this request. Is there an agreement on what to do and who should do it?

Comment: @Dominique Since there was no opposition, I merged the tags and they are now synonyms

Comment: @Machavity: thanks for the effort.